# Filter class files from compiled sourcesets to be added in a JAR in Gradle/Groovy

Tags: gradle, groovy, source-sets

I'm trying to include the compiled **.class** files from **Project1** into the jar for **Project2** since my project structure requires it to be done. For that, in the **build.gradle** for **Project2**, I write :

```
jar {
    from project(':Project1').sourceSets.main.output.classesDir
}
```

Which successfully does what I had to do. **But,** I now want to filter some of the classes that are added based on path and/or some pattern. For example, to include only delegate files, I tried this :

```
jar {
    from project(':Project1').sourceSets.main.output.classesDir {
        include '**/*Delegate*.class'
    }
}
```

But unfortunately it doesn't work. Is there a way to achieve this in Gradle/Groovy?

Answer (score 0):

Using Gradle 2.12, the following works for me (this is `build.gradle` for Project 2):

```
task myBuild(type: Jar) {
    baseName "myjar"
    from project(':Project1').sourceSets.main.output.classesDir, 
         { include "**/*Delegate*.*" } 
}
```

From [the doc for Jar.from](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar:from(java.lang.Object,%20groovy.lang.Closure)), note that it takes 2 arguments (hence, the comma is used).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12704/michael-easter)

Although I got my answer as well, I was just missing a parantheses. The correct and working code goes something like this :

```
jar {
    from (project(':Project1').sourceSets.main.output.classesDir) {
        include '**/*Delegate*.class'
    }
}
```